# Fourier series expansion of $ \cos(\alpha \theta) $

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series

From quite some time I'm struggling on proving the Fourier series expansion of $ \cos(\alpha n) $:

$$\cos(\alpha \theta) = \dfrac{\sin(\alpha \pi)}{\alpha \pi}\left(1 + 2\alpha^2\sum_{m = 1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}\cos(m\theta)}{m^2 - \alpha^2}\right)$$

Note: Here $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}- \mathbb{Z}$

I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: On what interval?

Comment: And presumably, when $\alpha$ is a non-integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $|n| < \pi$

Comment: Using $n$ as a real variable is very confusing, probably should use $x$ or $t$ or $\theta.$ $n$ is usually an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay, I'll edit the question in that case.

Comment: When $\alpha = 1$, the whole expression on RHS becomes 0. Check the expression or the problem you want to ask again?

Comment: @Yuki.F I'm pretty sure that the problem is correct :)

Comment: If true, I’m betting it only applies to non-integer $\alpha.$ @Yuki.F

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}- \mathbb{Z}$